# Mobile dropdown menu positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want this shape nav bar but it opens to the right of the page I made, what should I do?[ı want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSMn.png)[js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9l4J.png)[js2
[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NNcO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guyw3.png)[me navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHjYz.png)

When I press it, it does not appear on the mobile screen and opens on the far right, can you help me as in the image I want?

Comment: I would suggest hosting code somewhere like on codepen so it will be easier to provide you the solution. Here is the link it is free to use. https://codepen.io/

Comment: https://codepen.io/dari-baba/pens/showcase

Answer (score 0):

Replace the right offset with the left and you are good to go then IG.
Changed prefixed by the comment /* Change right to left */

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;500;600&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Logo and Navbar */
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*header*/
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 15px;
}

.header-main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header .logo img {
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 150px;
}

.header .nav-menu {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:before,
.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a .plus:before,
.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a .plus:after {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a:hover,
.header .menu>.menu-item:hover>a {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children:hover>.sub-menu {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children:hover>a .plus:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item {
  display: block;
}

.header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.header .open-nav-menu {
  height: 34px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .open-nav-menu span {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
}

.header .open-nav-menu span:before,
.header .open-nav-menu span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header .open-nav-menu span:before {
  top: -7px;
}

.header .open-nav-menu span:after {
  top: 7px;
}

.header .close-nav-menu {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header .close-nav-menu img {
  width: 16px;
}

.header .menu-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/*home section*/
.home-section {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('../images/logo.svg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* responsive */

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .header .menu-overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .header .nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
/*     right: -280px; */
/* change right to left */
    left: -280px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 280px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 15px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .header .nav-menu.open {
    visibility: visible;
/*     right: 0px; */
/* change right to left */
    left:0px;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children>a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item>a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item:first-child>a {
    border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:before,
  .header .menu>.menu-item>a .plus:after {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item-has-children.active>a .plus:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    padding: 0px;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .header .menu>.menu-item>.sub-menu>.menu-item>a {
    padding: 12px 45px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  }

  .header .close-nav-menu,
  .header .open-nav-menu {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```